# GAS webapps is not working. How to fix it?

Tags: google-apps-script, server-error

When I try to open my published webapps i get the following message:

> "Sorry, an error has occurred on the server. Wait a moment and try
> again."

I dont know how to fix it.
I have tried to duplicate my spreadsheet and publish my webapps again but i still get the same message
the url of the webapp is the following: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzgz8lPFftvtnXOC9rVQiuoXpFmKzfW7-6Ij1IZXY-0Q41hH8XI/dev?page=entrega&distrito=D6

Comment: This has been a common occurrence in the last few months with Apps Script. I suggest checking out [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and search for or file the issue with them

Comment: Could you please provide the code of your web app?